# Is any abelian subvariety of an abelian variety closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I am wondering because Milne [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf) in Proposition 10.1, page 42, takes any abelian subvariety $B$ of an abelian variety $A$, with $0\neq B\neq A$, then he takes an ample line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $A$ and he says that $\mathcal{L}|B$ is ample because of his result 6.6b (page 31), which says that the restriction of an ample line bundle to a closed subvariety is again ample.

Hence I suppose that $B$ is closed, but we didn't make any assumption about $B$. So every abelian subvariety of an abelian variety is closed, right? Or am I missing some hypotheses in this proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: Abelian varieties are proper over the base field. The image of a morphism from a proper variety to any other variety is always closed.